# LetsEncrypt Validation with Docker, Nginx, AWS ECS fails half of the time

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

Alright - I have some very interesting behavior going on in a Rails app when deploying to production on AWS ECS.

**A quick background:**

- Rails app, dockerized with nginx proxy up front
- Running AWS ELB up front as well
- Worked 100% fine before implementing SSL
- Started with this [blog post](http://chrisstump.online/2016/05/05/lets-encrypt-docker-rails/) and have since upgraded to dehydrated, most recent version
- I have ssh/root access to all of my servers in AWS, will run any recommended tests
- Certificate scripts work locally

---

So here's what's going on. Our CI/CD process goes through travis-ci, pushes the image to ECR, then updates our tasks/services in ECS to use that new image. Works great.

Now, after implementing the SSL functionality, it fails 100% of the time when trying to request and validate the certificate in the nginx container. It fails with 404 (see log output below).

I have been wrestling with this for almost a week now, and it's preventing us from going live. Here's my questions:

- How can I test and identify the issue?
- Why does only *one* server allow me to validate successfully?
- In what ways could I refactor this to get to a working solution?
- Could cloudflare be causing these issues?

I'm open to all ideas and help!

**More context:**

- I am able to successfully put a "test.txt" file in my $SSL_ROOT/.well-known/acme-challenges dir and view it in the browser
- $WELLKNOWN is defined and working in my config.sh file
- Even more odd, I can manually SSH, docker exec into my instances and run the exact same command successfully! But only on ONE of the servers, not both. This seems to be at complete random, and I have not been able to identify how/why it works when it occasionally does 1/20 times. (cloudflare?)
- Running linux optimized AMI for ECS (see os-release below)
- I am using http-01 validation
- I am running Cloudflare to manage our DNS (App is on a subdomain, Website on root domain)

Below are my docker-compose, nginx config, web_cmd.sh, and log output, with obvious values edited to example, etc:

Logs:

```
+ Generating account key...
+ Registering account key with ACME server...
 + Creating chain cache directory ./chains
Processing orders.example.com
 + Creating new directory ./certs/orders.example.com ...
 + Signing domains...
 + Generating private key...
 + Generating signing request...
 + Requesting authorization for orders.example.com...
 + 1 pending challenge(s)
 + Deploying challenge tokens...
 + Responding to challenge for orders.example.com authorization...
172.31.37.243 - - [21/May/2018:20:41:19 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/5z5x0pgn-eaoHTxvlvIHB6ZjdVu39DH2CjFDhlX-Hqo HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Let's Encrypt validation server; +https://www.letsencrypt.org)" "2600:1f14:ac6:4f10:505a:1249:9e33:edae, 108.162.245.41"
172.31.37.243 - - [21/May/2018:20:41:19 +0000] "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/5z5x0pgn-eaoHTxvlvIHB6ZjdVu39DH2CjFDhlX-Hqo HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Let's Encrypt validation server;     +https://www.letsencrypt.org)" "2600:3000:2710:300:0:0:0:1d, 172.68.174.5"
 + Cleaning challenge tokens...
 + Challenge validation has failed :(
ERROR: Challenge is invalid! (returned: invalid) (result: {
  "type": "http-01",
  "status": "invalid",
  "error": {
    "type": "urn:acme:error:unauthorized",
    "detail": "Invalid response from http://orders.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/5z5x0pgn-eaoHTxvlvIHB6ZjdVu39DH2CjFDhlX-Hqo: \"\u003chtml\u003e\r\n\u003chead\u003e\u003ctitle\u003e404 Not Found\u003c/title\u003e\u003c/head\u003e\r\n\u003cbody bgcolor=\"white\"\u003e\r\n\u003ccenter\u003e\u003ch1\u003e404 Not Found\u003c/h1\u003e\u003c/center\u003e\r\n\u003chr\u003e\u003ccenter\u003e    \"",
    "status": 403
  },
  "uri": "https://acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/OLGNI3nejESFWljtiNb1SYSA31r1nCLl2SGMTqY-a24/129269548",
  "token": "5z5x0pgn-eaoHTxvlvIHB6ZjdVu39DH2CjFDhlX-Hqo",
  "keyAuthorization": "5z5x0pgn-eaoHTxvlvIHB6ZjdVu39DH2CjFDhlX-Hqo.izK8nKawDYb0eZQodIC5v1Mb-w-yOqGDz2_9tC5arJg",
  "validationRecord": [
    {
      "url": "http://orders.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/5z5x0pgn-eaoHTxvlvIHB6ZjdVu39DH2CjFDhlX-Hqo",
      "hostname": "orders.example.com",
      "port": "80",
      "addressesResolved": [
        "104.27.178.217",
        "104.27.179.217",
        "2400:cb00:2048:1::681b:b2d9",
        "2400:cb00:2048:1::681b:b3d9"
      ],
      "addressUsed": "2400:cb00:2048:1::681b:b2d9"
        }
      ]
    })
```

Nginx Config:

```
upstream puma {
  server app:3000;
}

server {
  # expect SSL requests, try to use HTTP2
  listen 443 ssl;

  # define our domain; CHANGE ME
  server_name orders.example.com;

  # define the public application root
  root   $RAILS_ROOT/public;
  index  index.html;

  # configure SSL
  ssl_certificate $SSL_CERT_HOME/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key $SSL_CERT_HOME/privkey.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_dhparam $SSL_CERT_HOME/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  # define where Nginx should write its logs
  access_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.error.log;

  # deny requests for files that should never be accessed
  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log)$ {
    deny all;
  }

  # serve static (compiled) assets directly if they exist (for rails production)
  location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
    try_files $uri @rails;

    access_log off;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version

    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  # send non-static file requests to the app server
  location / {
    try_files $uri @rails;
  }

  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # prevent infinite request loop
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
}

server {
  # many clients will send unencrypted requests
  listen 80;

  # accept unencrypted ACME challenge requests
  location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    alias $SSL_ROOT/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
  }

  # force insecure requests through SSL
  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: app_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: app_pass
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

  web:
    environment:
      CA_SSL: "false" # change to "true" for production

    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    links:
      - app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

    volumes:
      - ssl_certs:/var/www/ssl

  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - '1080:1080'

  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/example
    environment:
      - DATABASE_NAME=example
      - DATABASE_USER=app_user
      - DATABASE_PASS=app_pass
      - DATABASE_HOST=postgres
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - RAILS_ENV
      - SELENIUM_REMOTE_HOST=selenium
    expose:
      - "3000"
    depends_on: 
      - 'postgres'
      - 'selenium'
      - 'mailcatcher'

volumes:
  postgres:
  ssl_certs:
```

Dockerfile-nginx:

```
# Base image:
FROM nginx

# install essential Linux packages
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install apache2-utils curl

# establish where Nginx should look for files
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/example
#
# where we store everything SSL-related
ENV SSL_ROOT /var/www/ssl

# where Nginx looks for SSL files
ENV SSL_CERT_HOME $SSL_ROOT/certs/live

# copy over the script that is run by the container
COPY web_cmd.sh /tmp/

# Set our working directory inside the image
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# create log directory
RUN mkdir log

# copy over static assets
COPY public public/

# Copy Nginx config template
COPY config/nginx.conf /tmp/docker_example.nginx

# substitute variable references in the Nginx config template for real values from the environment
# put the final config in its place
RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT:$SSL_ROOT:$SSL_CERT_HOME' < /tmp/docker_example.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

#RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
#ADD config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

# Define the script we want run once the container boots
# Use the "exec" form of CMD so Nginx shuts down gracefully on SIGTERM (i.e. `docker stop`)
CMD [ "/tmp/web_cmd.sh" ]
```

web_cmd.sh (docker command for nginx container):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# initialize the dehydrated environment
setup_letsencrypt() {

  # create the directory that will serve ACME challenges
  mkdir -p .well-known/acme-challenge
  chmod -R 755 .well-known # See https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated/blob/master/docs/domains_txt.md
  echo "orders.example.com" > domains.txt

  # See https://github.com/lukas2511/letsencrypt.sh/blob/master/docs/staging.md
  echo "CA=\"https://acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\"" > config.sh

  # See https://github.com/lukas2511/letsencrypt.sh/blob/master/docs/wellknown.md
  echo "WELLKNOWN=\"$SSL_ROOT/.well-known/acme-challenge\"" >> config.sh

  # fetch stable version of dehydrated
  curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lukas2511/dehydrated/v0.6.2/dehydrated" > dehydrated
  chmod 755 dehydrated
}

# creates self-signed SSL files
# these files are used in development and get production up and running so dehydrated can do its work
create_pems() {
  openssl req \
      -x509 \
      -nodes \
      -newkey rsa:1024 \
      -keyout privkey.pem \
      -out fullchain.pem \
      -days 3650 \
      -sha256 \
      -config <(cat <<EOF
[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = subject
x509_extensions    = x509_ext

[ subject ]
commonName = orders.example.com

[ x509_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alternate_names

[ alternate_names ]
DNS.1 = localhost
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
EOF
)

  openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
  chmod 600 *.pem
}

# if we have not already done so initialize Docker volume to hold SSL files
if [ ! -d "$SSL_CERT_HOME" ]; then
  mkdir -p $SSL_CERT_HOME
  chmod 755 $SSL_ROOT
  chmod -R 700 $SSL_ROOT/certs
  cd $SSL_CERT_HOME
  create_pems
  cd $SSL_ROOT
  setup_letsencrypt
fi

# if we are configured to run SSL with a real certificate authority run dehydrated to retrieve/renew SSL certs
if [ "$CA_SSL" = "true" ]; then

  touch $SSL_ROOT/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt
  # Nginx must be running for challenges to proceed
  # run in daemon mode so our script can continue
  nginx

  sleep 25

  cd $SSL_ROOT

  # retrieve/renew SSL certs
  ./dehydrated --accept-terms --config config.sh --cron

  # copy the fresh certs to where Nginx expects to find them
  cp $SSL_ROOT/certs/orders.example.com/fullchain.pem $SSL_ROOT/certs/orders.example.com/privkey.pem $SSL_CERT_HOME

  # pull Nginx out of daemon mode
  nginx -s stop
fi

# start Nginx in foreground so Docker container doesn't exit
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

output of `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that helps me here. I'm so close, signing certs successfully, just can't persist them and get it to work during the initial container execution. If you need *anything* else from me to make it clear, I will provide it happily.

Comment: I do not understand "it fails 100% of the time" and "Why does only one server allow me to validate successfully", how do they relate? Also if you have a 404 it means the validator tries to fetch a resource at an URL for which your webserver replied there is no content. You could start by having a look at your webserver logfiles. Note that you are a little offtopic since your question is not related to programming. (but congrats for using the proper `example.com` name as well as IPv6!)

Comment: Another inconsistency: your webserver is configured to look at `$SSL_ROOT` but you say "I am able to successfully put a "test.txt" file in my $SSL_CERT_HOME and view it in the browser" is this a typo or did you mix the two? Also note that the query for validation comes over HTTP and hence should be separated from all the SSL stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PatrickMevzek - here's the clarifications:

It fails 100% of the time when it's ran as a deploy script via `web_cmd.sh`, or rather, when the docker image is pulled and the cmd is first executed. I have never successfully been able to validate through my automated script.

In regards to $SSL_ROOT, that was a typo. I can confirm that my nginx setup works, becuase i can access a text file I put in that directory. I understand that 404 is an indication of a web server mis config, but in this case I've confirmed that it is working correctly.

Comment: Also - the "why does one server allow me to validate" may have given a hint as to why it inconsistently validates. For example, the `web_cmd.sh` runs and fails, but if I SSH into the instance, `docker exec -it` into the container and run `./dehydrated --accept-terms --config config.sh --cron` it works 1/20 times. I'm starting to think it's related to cloudfront proxy because it is so random and I can't seem to find the cause for success/fail between the two instances.  After I manually generate certificates, the other server will never validate successfully for some reason.

Comment: If there's anything else I can do to give you clarity, I'll respond immediately. I'm at my wits end here! Thanks again

Comment: I kind of wanted to suggest indeed that you try to remove some parts of the system to pinpoint where the error may be, by dichotomy. The proxy would be the first thing I would try to bypass to see if it is the culprit or not.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was thinking the same thing. I'll start there.